# Can we use "but also" without "not only"

Tags: conjunctions

let's begin with the example:

> Women achieved the abolition of bigamy in 1950(for example). This action, in turn, paved the way for other women's rights, **but also** led to a huge backlash against them.

By using this instance, I wanted to ask whether "**but also**" can only be used with "not only" or we can use it separately.
I should add that, the structure of the sentence and refinements could be done to it is not noteworthy to me since it is just an example to discuss the abovementioned inquiry although if you provide it apart from replying to the chief question I appreciate it. Thank you in advance for your contribution.

Comment: Yes, it can be used separately, each word having its normal meaning.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is correct, but it's not using **but also** as a single construct. It's using **but** as a conjunction, and it's using **also** as an adverb, and  it's mostly a coincidence that they're next to each other.

We could replace either with a synonym and not change the meaning of the sentence:

> ... **although it** also led to a huge backlash against them.

Or

> ... but **additionally** led to a huge backlash against them.